SSRS Visual Studio data source issue
We have an SSRS report server with a data source called "DS123", which contains the data source and initial catalog that most of our reports use.
When I create a new report in Visual Studio I create the data source in VS with the exact string that DS123 uses but when I deploy the report to the SSRS server I always have to manually select "A shared data source" and point it to the DS123 data source on the SSRS server, even though "A custom data source" has the exact same connection string.  I get an "anonymous login" error if I don't manually set it to the data source on the SSRS server.
Any suggestions on how to not have to do this every time for a new report?


You would typically create a shared data source in Visual Studio. By default the data sources are not overwritten when you deploy the reports so as long as it has exactly the same name and it's set as a shared data source in VS, then the deployed report will just look for a shared data source on the server with the same name.
